# How do I format both the Date and Time at once in mysql?

Tags: php, mysql

sorry for the noob question. But how do I format the date and time at once?

Thanks in advance!

```
<?
$sql = "SELECT *,date_format(course_date, '%d %b %Y') as course_date_format FROM course WHERE course_status = ?  ORDER BY course_create_by";
$sql = "SELECT *,from_time_format(course_date, '%h:%i') as course_from_time_format FROM course WHERE course_status = ?  ORDER BY course_create_by";
$sql = "SELECT *,to_time_format(course_date, '%h:%i') as course_to_time_format FROM course WHERE course_status = ?  ORDER BY course_create_by";

$sth = $dbh->prepare($sql);
$sth->execute(array($status));
while($result = $sth->fetch(PDO::FETCH_OBJ)){

$course_id = $result->course_id;
$course_title = nl2br($result->{"course_title_".$lang});
$course_title1 = nl2br($result->{"course_title1_".$lang}); 
$course_date = $result->course_date_format;

$course_from_time = $result->course_from_time;
$course_to_time = $result->course_to_time;
$course_time = $course_from_time_format."-".$course_to_time_format;
?>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this,

```
date_format(course_date, '%d %b %Y %H %i %s')
```

`H` => 24 hour format
`h` => 12 hour format

[Reference](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/func_date_format.asp)

Comment: Thanks dude! just what i was looking for

Comment: yea I will, sorry it says that I have to wait 9 min to accept your answer. But I will dont worry. Thanks again